# Activating programmatically custom script on page load

Tags: development, jquery

I have small problem. The thing is I need to have a method on page load that will execute one script only if web.allProperties has one property, but I dont know how to call that script?

So this is how the code looks like:

```
if(web.AllProperties.ContainsKey("Key1")
{
   add script to page and execute
}
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

The `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method will do the trick for you.
Have a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx